# Manually apply puppet class

Tags: windows, puppet

I am testing a puppet init.pp file (on windows) that looks something like:

```
class myclass {    
 package { 'java':
    ensure => installed,
    provider => 'msi',
    source => 'S:\puppet-repo\jdk1.6.0_31.msi',
    install_options => { 'INSTALLDIR' => 'C:\tools\java' },
  }
}
```

Then my site.pp file looks like:

```
node default {
  include myclass
}
```

I created a tests/init.pp file that just calls the myclass module:

```
class { 'myclass': }
```

I can run the tests/init.pp file and it does install java correctly. I was wondering if there is a way to just run the myclass module from the command line without creating a separate tests/init.pp file. Or maybe I could move the `package` statement in myclass to its own .pp file and include that in init.pp and then I could run that separate .pp file if I wanted to. What is the more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a trick for verifying syntax if you don't already know:

```
puppet parser validate my_file.pp
```

Now, how you approach spot-testing a new class can vary based on your deployment but I can tell you how I do it, and perhaps it will make sense in your case.  Or perhaps everyone on ServerFault will tell me how wrong I am.

In any given environment I have a set of node declarations using inheritance:

```
node base_production_environment {
  include ssh
  include ntp
  include whatever_else
}

node /prod-app\d+\.mycompany\.com/ inherits base_production_environment { }
```

Now, when I write a new class, I want to test it on a particular system first before rolling it out, so I add a more specific (by hostname) node declaration so that it will override the less specific (by regular expression) declaration, like so:

```
node 'prod-app7.mycompany.com' inherits base_production_environment {
  include my_new_class
}
```

I simplified this a lot to highlight using specific node declarations for spot-checking new classes.  We also use [environments](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/environment.html) to roll out changes to less critical environments prior to rolling them out to production, etc.

---

So I just re-read your question and it occurred to me that you may be using a pushed modules directory approach, rather than using a puppetmaster.  If that's true, you can include a class for testing purposes with something like:

```
puppet apply --modulepath=C:\puppet-modules\ -e "include my_class"
```

I don't know if that's the correct directory syntax for puppet under Windows, though.

Comment: Thanks for this input. The pushed directory approach is more what I'm working with. That helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could also run:
puppet agent -t --tags *your_class_name*

So in your case:

`puppet agent -t --tags my_new_class`